# Functors, forming pairs "coretraction–retraction", what are they called?

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

I asked this two months ago at [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681751/functors-forming-a-pair-coretraction-retraction-what-are-they-called), but without success, so I hope that somebody at MO could help.

Let $I$ and $K$ be two categories. Let us consider two functors from $I$ to $K$:

- a covariant functor ${\mathcal F}:I\to K$, and
- a contravariant functor ${\mathcal G}:I\to K$,

and suppose that for each morphism $\varphi:A\to B$ in $I$ the following equalities hold:
$$
{\mathcal F}(A)={\mathcal G}(A),\quad {\mathcal F}(B)={\mathcal G}(B),
$$
$$
{\mathcal G}(\varphi)\circ {\mathcal F}(\varphi)=1_{{\mathcal F}(A)}
$$
In other words, ${\mathcal G}(\varphi)$ is a retraction for ${\mathcal F}(\varphi)$ (and ${\mathcal F}(\varphi)$ is a coretraction for ${\mathcal G}(\varphi)$).

Question:

> what is such a pair of functors $({\mathcal F},{\mathcal G})$ called?

---

Let me give an example that I have in mind. Suppose $G$ is an LP-group, i.e. a locally compact group which is a projective limit of its Lie quotient groups. Denote by $\lambda(G)$ the system of compact normal subgroups $H$ in $G$ such that the quotient group $G/H$ is a Lie group. Then,
$$
G=\projlim_{H\in\lambda(G)}G/H.
$$
We endow $\lambda(G)$ with the partial order
$$
H\le L\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad H\supseteq L,
$$
and this allows to consider $\lambda(G)$ as a category.

Now let us consider the space ${\mathcal C}(G)$ of continuous functions on $G$ and for each group $H\in\lambda(H)$ let us denote by ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$ the subspace of functions in ${\mathcal C}(G)$ which are invariant with respect to the shifts on elements of $H$:
$$
u(g\cdot h)=u(g)=u(h\cdot g),\qquad g\in G, \ h\in H
$$
We can note that
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\cong{\mathcal C}(G/H),\qquad H\in\lambda(G).
$$

Now we can define the functor ${\mathcal F}$ as the one that turns $H\in\lambda(H)$ into the space ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$ and the pair $H\le L$ into the natural emdedding
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\subseteq {\mathcal C}(G:L)
$$
And the functor ${\mathcal G}$ again turns $H\in\lambda(H)$ into the space ${\mathcal C}(G:H)$, but the pair $H\le L$ is turned into the natural projection
$$
{\mathcal C}(G:H)\gets {\mathcal C}(G:L)
$$
that turns each function $u\in{\mathcal C}(G:L)$ into its mean value with respect to the subgroup $H$:
$$
{\mathcal G}(H,L)(u)(g)=\int_H u(g\cdot h) \ \mu_H(d h),\qquad g\in G
$$
(here $\mu_H$ is the normalized Haar measure on $H$).

I am interested in this construction because it is used in Harmonic Analysis for proving some untrivial results, for example François Bruhat in his paper [Distributions sur un groupe localement compact et applications à l’étude des représentations des groupes p-adiques](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1961__89__43_0)  of 1961 uses this to prove that the space ${\mathcal D}(G)$ of test functions on a locally compact group $G$ is complete. (But he replaces everywhere ${\mathcal C}(G)$ by ${\mathcal D}(G)$.)

I thought that perhaps this construction has a special name in category theory since it looks very natural.

---

**Remark.** I used the term "coretraction–retraction" in the title, but I think it's worth saying that these functors don't form a "coretraction–retraction pair", since this is not a situation when the composition of functors gives the identity functor: we can't write
$$
{\mathcal G}\circ {\mathcal F}=\operatorname{id}_I.
$$

Comment: TeX note: `\mathcal`, like the other AMS-style "modern" formatting commands and unlike the plain TeX, takes its argument in the usual macro style.  Thus, the extra braces are redundant: $\mathcal FG$ `\mathcal FG` means the same as `\mathcal{F}G`, and does not affect $G$ (as opposed to, for example, ${\bf F}G$ `{\bf F}G` versus $\bf FG$ `\bf FG`, where it does matter).

Comment: I do not have an answer, but I will point out that what you have is a precisely a functor from $I$ to a certain category determined by $K$. Maybe the latter category has a name. Its objects are the $K$-objects. A morphism $X\to Y$ is a pair $X\to Y\to X$ of $K$-morphisms whose composition is $1_X$, and composition is the obvious thing.

Comment: @LSpice thank you, I didn't know this.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie yes, people at MSE also told this.